# Vertex AI Workbench not running under specified service account for schedule-based recurring executions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, google-secret-manager

I have a Workbench notebook that uses service account. It works when directly running through Workbench.

There are 2 ways to schedule an execution for async runs:

1. One-time execution
2. Schedule-based recurring execution

In both cases there is an advanced option to provide service account in which the script runs with default being

> Use Vertex AI Training’s default service account

My service account is passed into execution for 'One-time execution' which can be verified from 'VIEW CUSTOM JOB INPUTS IN JSON'. Here's a snippet:

```
{
  "workerPoolSpecs": [
     ... bunch of config here ...
  ],
  "serviceAccount": "XXXXXXXXXX-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

It executes fine.

'Schedule-based recurring execution', however, does not pass the service account even when specified and fails the script with `PermissionDenied: 403 Request had insufficient authentication scopes.` Here's the snippet from 'VIEW CUSTOM JOB INPUTS IN JSON' for schedule-based recurring execution with the missing 'serviceAccount' key

```
{
  "workerPoolSpecs": [
     ... bunch of config here ...
  ]
}
```

This appears to be a GCP bug unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Could you try using credentials as `key_path = "path/to/service_account.json"  credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(key_path,scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"],)`? To use a custom service account you can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/custom-service-account).

Comment: I guess I'll have to use this as a workaround. Thanks!

Comment: @Prajna Rai T while the workaround is possible, it's not easy as notebook executor runs on a container without other files that is accessible from the workbench.

Comment: I looked at the code and was not able to spot the bug, I will try to reproduce and get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve the error of insufficient authentication scopes you can try including the authentication scope as `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"`.

For example, you can include the below lines in your code.

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account

key_path = "path/to/service_account.json"  
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    key_path,
    scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"],)
```

Also, you can consider creating a [custom service account](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/custom-service-account) as per your requirement.

Comment: I marked this as the correct answer as it's the only viable workaround at the moment. Service account file isn't automatically included unless you use a custom docker image with the file included. I used `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env variable instead of loading it through python code as shown above.